# How to get rid of Function calls are not supported in decorators in Angular aot compiling?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, angular-cli

I am testing a [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) Angular2x [Wrapper](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts). At first, I had no problem using Angular CLI (1.6.1) "ng serve" and profiling performance with Chrome. Then, i tried to use ahead-of-time compiling to see how that affects the performance.

So, using:

```
ng serve --aot
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ChartModule' was called.
```

Now, i know that aot generates factory code for modules and somehow "transformes" templates to VanillaJS, things get a bit tricky here and i couldn't understand how ngc is going to generate factory code for a module that requires an external library.

I got this App.Module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

declare var require: any;
export function getHighchartsModule() {
  return  require('highcharts');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartModule.forRoot(getHighchartsModule) // This causes the error
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My Package.json dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
```

My questions are :
Is there anything i can do here to avoid the mentioned compiling error ?
Can anyone explain why does this happen ? (optional)

Comment: I have already encoutered this error and it was about fat arrow functions. In your case, I don't know, sorry ...

Comment: @trichetriche i have encountered that error in arrow functions in the Providers property of the decorator and i had bad time resolving it. This one is different :(

Comment: is that the wat to use the HighChartsModule ? Can't you do something else with the `forRoot` ? And require should not be used in Typescript either, so maybe you could find a workaround on that basis ?

Comment: I am not an expert in javascript nor in angular, i need some explanations so i can find a workaround. Waiting for a savior...

Comment: Oh well, in this case, **[see this github issue](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/163)** !

Comment: @trichetriche That helped i used the workaround mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/156)

Comment: Great ! let me post an answer so that you can close your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mentioning the Github issue [here](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/156). The following solution worked for me.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Angular Highcharts Imports
import {HighchartsStatic} from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService'; 
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

// Factory Function
export function highchartsFactory() {
  var hc = require('highcharts');
  return hc;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartModule // Import Module Here
  ],
  providers: [ // Provide Service Here
    {
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory 
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem with angular in general. Angular compiler wants the `forRoot` code to be completely static.

As an example, in the following code even the assignment of the static variable will cause this error:

```
static forRoot(config: MyConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    MyConfigService.config = config;// This line with cause an error
    return {
      ngModule: HttpTrackerLibModule,
    };
  }
```

If you are *not* library creator there is nothing much you can do but try library-specific solutions like the one above. But if you are a library creator you can try a static approach as follows:

1. Create an injection token:

   `export const USER_OPTIONS = new InjectionToken<MyConfig>('USER_OPTIONS');`
2. Provide the token in your library Module

```js
static forRoot(config: MyConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
            return {
                ngModule: HttpTrackerLibModule,
                providers: [{
                    provide: USER_OPTIONS,
                    useValue: config
                }],
            };
        }
```

3. Use the token using DI elsewhere:

```js
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(@Inject(USER_OPTIONS) private _config: MyConfig) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose an additional answer if it helps folks get past the error. I had two nearly identical applications on **Angular 11** sharing the same Library module that has a `static forRoot` method declaration for custom injection configuration.

```
@NgModule()
export class TheModule {
  static forRoot(...) {
   ... 
  }
}
```

App A worked as expected, App B threw the error in question.
Of course my two apps were different in nature, so this narrows it down to `infrastructure` or `configuration` differences.

### Investigation

View the shared module's `compiled` code e.g. `the-module.module.d.ts` to see if there are differences there:

**from the scope of the working application:**

```
// the-module.module.d.ts
import * ...
...

export declare class TheModule {
    static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta<TheModule, [typeof ɵngcc4.AComponent, ...]
    static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDef<TheModule>;
}
```

Note the `emod` (Module) and `einj` (Injection) definitions.

**from the scope of broken app**

It is missing these definitions :

```
// the-module.module.d.ts
export declare class TheModule {
}
```

Ok so why is the module empty for the broken app!? It must be something with compilation! Looking at the root `tsconfig.json`

For the **broken** app:

The following `angularCompilerOptions` setting was enabled:

```
// woops, remove this to use the newer compiler for angular versions > 9.0
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
 }
```

This was flack left over from previous days. **Upon removing this, the error went away**, and it enabled the compiler to interact with the shared library module and its types were populated.

When compiling AOT take a look at the compiler options documentation: https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options to see the details.
The error message that @AngularJs prints, treating it as a `decorator` is a "side effect", and unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same issue. Try removing the `getHighchartsModule` export from your `App.Module.ts` and put the exported function in its own file. Then import it into `App.Module.ts`.

I have not figured out why this happens yet.

Comment: I actually resolved this following this [workaround](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/156), but still i didn't get the root of the issue. Once i have it i will post an answer.

Comment: See my answer above. Might also be a root cause depending on compilation settings, angularCompilerOptions in your tsconfig.