# Function calls are not supported in decorators but

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

#### Description

I wrote an angular library SxfedModule and use it in a different angular applications. when I packaged my application with the library, evenything works fine without --prod.

#### Reproduction Steps

Use this library in a new angular application which is generated by the angular cli by calling SxfedModule .forRoot() in the app.module.ts.

NgModule of the library:

```
    import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';  
    import { SxfedformModule } from './component/sxfedform/sxfedform.module';
    export const ElChildModules: any = {
      SxfedformModule,
    }
    export const ELMODULES_GROUP: any[] = [
      SxfedformModule,
    ]
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        SxfedformModule.forRoot(),
      ],
      exports: ELMODULES_GROUP,
    })
    class SxfedModule {
      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: SxfedModule,
          providers: [],
        };
      }
    }
    export {
      SxfedModule,
    };
```

NgModule of the application:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
   browser/animations';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ElModule } from 'element-angular'; 
    import { SxfedModule } from 'sxfed-angular-ui';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ElModule.forRoot(),
        SxfedModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      ],
      providers: [
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Try ng build --prod

### Error

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'SxfedModule' was called.
```

### Your Environment

Angular CLI: 7.2.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.2

Thank you for reading my problem.
Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283479/how-to-get-rid-of-function-calls-are-not-supported-in-decorators-in-angular-aot

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work

Comment: Is that the complete error log?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the library package error, but I don't know where it is